# How to set OR in isset_POST

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to set `OR` in `isset($_POST)`, so that there will be only one button to save in database.

`btnusersave` is the one that will save the whole data in dialog,
while `saveuseraccess` button is the one that saves the check boxes in database.

This is my code for `btnusersave`

```
 <?php  
    $eventrequirements = 'unchecked';
    if (isset($_POST['btnusersave'])) 
    {
        if (isset($_POST['eventrequirements'])) 
        {
            $eventrequirements = $_POST['eventrequirements'];
            if ($eventrequirements == 'net') {
                $eventrequirements = 'checked';
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: For OR :- `if(isset($_POST['btnusersave']) || isset($_POST['eventrequirements']) ){`, but i think in your case you need `AND` so `if(isset($_POST['btnusersave']) && isset($_POST['eventrequirements']) ){`

Comment: where is `saveuseraccess`? no where in code\

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
<?php  
    $eventrequirements = 'unchecked';

    if (isset($_POST['btnusersave'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['eventrequirements'])) {
            $eventrequirements = $_POST['eventrequirements'];
            if ($eventrequirements == 'net') {
                $eventrequirements = 'checked';
            }
        }
    }else if ( isset($_POST['saveuseraccess']) ) {
        //do alternate code (to save checkboxes) here
    }

?>
```